# An asymptotic about the ratio of Gamma function.

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

I want to show for $1\leq b <\infty$,

$$\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}2)\Gamma(\frac{a+b}2)}\right)^{1/b}\sim\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$ with absolute constants of equivalence.

I am trying to find some gamma function asymptotics but didn't have any idea. I also tried [Gautschi’s Inequality](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6) but fail to prove it.

Any suggestions would be welcome and thanks to you!

Comment: Consider Stirling's approximation

Comment: Do you mean as $a\to\infty$?